# Issue with the update manager

Tags: 12.04, update-manager

Whenever I check for updates in the update manager I get a message saying that there is an issue with my internet connection and that it needs to be checked. additionally under details, this is the message that's there-

```
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ui-toolkit/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ui-toolkit/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

issue is, that despite this message, i get a number of updates, that i install, and after that is done, there's a message at the top of the update manager saying that the package details are 'x' days old.
currently x=70

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `ui-toolkit` PPA is deprecated, you need to edit it, either manually in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file or in the gnome control center - software sources menu, changing the appropriate entries from

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ui-toolkit/ppa/ubuntu
```

to:

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa/ubuntu
```

So, change `ui-toolkit` to `ubuntu-sdk-team`.